# This Backbone Marionette code to fetch from REST api seems wrong

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

so this isn't a specific problem so much as a question on best practices, I guess.  I am just jumping into Backbone and Marionette and my head is swimming from reading a dozen articles and tutorials.  Each one seems to do things a little differently and none goes very in-depth, leaving out lots of details.  I found a Marionette jsFiddle online (http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/5dMjD/) that provided a static model to a view and I managed to hack it to fetch data from a REST api (Foursquare public API - http://bit.ly/1cy3MZe)

However, it doesn't seem to jive right with Marionette's promise of "less boilerplate". In fact, I know I'm doing all sorts of hacky things, I just don't know what and my head is going to explode taking it all in.

Here's the code in case you don't want to look at the Fiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>MarionetteJS (Backbone.Marionette) Playground - jsFiddle demo by tonicboy</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://marionettejs.com/downloads/backbone.marionette.js"></script>
  <style type='text/css'>
    #main span {
    background-color:#ffc;
    font-weight: bold;
}
  </style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
// Define the app and a region to show content
// -------------------------------------------
var App = new Marionette.Application();
App.addRegions({
    "mainRegion": "#main"
});
// Create a module to contain some functionality
// ---------------------------------------------
App.module("SampleModule", function (Mod, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    // Define a view to show
    // ---------------------
    var MainView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: "#sample-template"
    });
    // Define a controller to run this module
    // --------------------------------------
    var Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({
        initialize: function (options) {
            this.region = options.region
        },
        show: function () {
            var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
                url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4afc4d3bf964a520512122e3?oauth_token=EWTYUCTSZDBOVTYZQ3Z01E54HMDYEPZMWOC0AKLVFRBIEXV4&v=20130808',
                toJSON: function () {
                    return _.clone(this.attributes.response);
                }
            })
            myBook = new Book();
            myBook.bind('change', function (model, response) {
                var view = new MainView({
                    el: $("#main"),
                    model: model
                });
                this.region.attachView(view);
                this.region.show(view);
            }, this);
            myBook.fetch();
        }
    });
    // Initialize this module when the app starts
    // ------------------------------------------
    Mod.addInitializer(function () {
        Mod.controller = new Controller({
            region: App.mainRegion
        });
        Mod.controller.show();
    });
});
// Start the app
// -------------
App.start();
});//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
     <h1>A Marionette Playground</h1>
</header>
<article id="main"></article>
<script type="text/html" id="sample-template">
    put some <span><%= venue.name %></span> here.
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the response object in the Devloper tools. You seem to be getting only 1 object and it has a single `name` attribute..  http://imgur.com/UI4A1hA

Comment: Yes, this is a single item (Model), not a list (Collection).  You can click on the FourSquare API link above and see the full response for yourself.  But my question is more related to best practices and recommended Marionette patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked too much with `Backbone Marionette` , but the general approach you follwed was pretty ok for the first time.

Also I made some small changes to the code. As the Model can be defined only once outside the scope of the controller as it makes more sense. You might even use the same Model in other views . So it is better the Model definition is available in the entire scope. 
Also creating a new instance of the model before passing it to the controller. Check the code.

Again I am not too well versed with Marionette and I could think of these of the top of my head.

```
// Define the app and a region to show content
// -------------------------------------------

var App = new Marionette.Application();

App.addRegions({
    "mainRegion": "#main"
});

// Create a module to contain some functionality
// ---------------------------------------------

App.module("SampleModule", function (Mod, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

    // Define a view to show
    // ---------------------

    var MainView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: "#sample-template"
    });

    // Move this to outside the Controller
    // as this gives access to other Views
    // Otherwise you would have to declare a New Model inside every controller
    var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4afc4d3bf964a520512122e3?oauth_token=EWTYUCTSZDBOVTYZQ3Z01E54HMDYEPZMWOC0AKLVFRBIEXV4&v=20130808',
        toJSON: function () {
            return _.clone(this.attributes.response);
        }
    })

 // Define a controller to run this module
    // --------------------------------------
    var Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({

        initialize: function (options) {
            this.region = options.region;
            this.model = options.model;
            // Listen to the change event and trigger the method
            // I would prefer this as this is a cleaner way of binding and
            // handling events
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.renderRegion);
        },
        show: function () {
            this.model.fetch();
        },
        renderRegion: function () {
            var view = new MainView({
                el: $("#main"),
                model: this.model
            });
            this.region.attachView(view);
            this.region.show(view);
        }
    });


    // Initialize this module when the app starts
    // ------------------------------------------

    Mod.addInitializer(function () {
        // I would create the model here and pass it to the controller
        var myBook = new Book();
        Mod.controller = new Controller({
            region: App.mainRegion,
            model: myBook
        });
        Mod.controller.show();
    });
});

// Start the app
// -------------

App.start();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/5dMjD/5/)**

Comment: There are some great edits here. I was going to eventually move the Model outside, but you're right.  Moving the event binding to the initialize is much cleaner.  Thanks for the answer.  I'm going to leave the question open for a couple days to see what other contributions I might get.

Comment: sure.. Not a problem.. Glad to have helped :)